# Does 0% APR mean I'm not charged interest?

Tags: credit-card, interest

If a credit card says you get something like, "0% APR for the first 12 months," does that mean you can get by with paying only minimum payments and not have any accrued interest build up?

If so, wouldn't it be better if they just advertised it as being of no interest?

If not, what's the difference  between 0% APR and whether or not you pay interest?

Comment: The law requires that they have the word APR and its value in their ad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 0% APR = no interest. APR = Annual Percentage Rate. As in, the lender gets an annual percentage returned to them for lending you money. This is the opposite of APY, which is Annual Percentage Yield, or the money that an investment yields.

Comment: APR is Annual Percentage Rate.  And Yield is the actual total return in a year considering compounded earnings of the Rate.